# PIXI load file from device and without server

Tags: javascript, loading, pixi.js

Good afternoon. I would like PIXI.js to work without a web server. So that the textures can be loaded from the device and don't using ajax.

```
PIXI.Texture.from('C:/Users/ProUser/Desktop/file/examples/assets/bg.png', {crossOrigin: ''});
```

This code not working. Help)
P.S i beginner to pixi and i bad know englis sry :)